# Why doesn't "completely" work in the sentence "My first choice is completely Oxford"?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

My student said "My first choice is completely Oxford" but I corrected it by changing the word "completely" to something else such as "absolutely".

I said that it would be more natural, but I'm not sure how to explain why I made that correction in detail.

Can someone please help me explain it better? 
Thank you!

Comment: You are right to trust your ear for conversation. While 'completely' gets the point across, what is complete, the choices? The first choice is completely the first, or the only choice? It is clearer to say my first choice is absolutely Oxford, no question about that as my first choice.

Comment: Actually, to the Great Unwashed here in the US midlands, "Oxford" is a meaningless term.  Are you talking about a dictionary, a university, or a shoe?

Comment: When I first read the title, I thought that the question involved a hiring manager talking about a candidate.

Comment: Ah, sorry everyone I should have provided more clarity. My Japanese student is going to have an MBA interview at Oxford university tomorrow and he practiced some interview questions with me. When I asked him "Did you apply for other schools?", he answered with "To be honest, I am interested in Canbridge as well, but my first choice is completely Oxford".

Comment: @Yosef Baskin 
I think so too. But it was hard to explain why I would choose ABSOLUTELY instead since it's synonymous in terms of grammar and meaning with COMPLETELY.

Comment: @Hot Licks 
I mean the university :)

Comment: @GlobalCharm 
Haha that happens. But yeah it's actually about an MBA interview at Oxford.

Comment: @AnnaMinkova Good question. It's hard to explain and I can understand your frustration. Technically speaking there is nothing necessarily wrong (grammatically) with the sentence. The definitions are extremely similar. That said it would sound unidiomatic and very odd to native speakers. The reason is b/c *"completely"* is used typically to grade something on a scale or range from minimal to maximal. *"Absolutely"* is not used that way. It's used when there is no chance for variation. The options/choices are final. They are similar types of superlative adverbs but very slightly different.

Comment: "Overwhelmingly Oxford," "far and away Oxford", "definitely Oxford".

Answer (score 3):

Could your first choice be *partially* Oxford?  If no, then it cannot be *completely* Oxford either.

I would understand the sentence "My first choice is *completely* Oxford" as "My first choice *for this job hire is a very* Oxford *person, totally and completely Oxford through and through. He/she is a died-in-the-wool Oxford grad.*"

If you are trying to say "My first choice *of universities I want to attend* is Oxford" it should be "My first choice is *absolutely* Oxford."

Comment: I see! I'll show your explanation to my student. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Japanese people have some verbs whose English equivalents are close to completely or absolutely, with some middle ground. However, "completely" is not the accurate description because "completely" describes a state that can be quantified (and "completely" might describe "totally" or "100%"), whereas "absolutely" is a black-or-white term that is a state of totality or not at all. You might want to emphasize that the meaning of "absolutely" leans towards the feeling of "certainly" and away from "completely".

As a side note, "totally" is a colloquialism that for some reason we use, though it's probably not correct for the same reasons despite our usage of it in a similar fashion.

Now I'm curious what his sentence would be in Japanese...

Answer (score 1):

"Completely" generally means that something is maximal on a scale - which is probably why your student assumed it would be appropriate - but usually precedes an adjective rather than a noun (completely full, completely straight, completely dry). Some adjectives don't correspond to scales with clear endpoints, which is why "completely tall", "completely wide", etc. sound a bit off. Search for "the completely test" to find some interesting linguistic commentary on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

This is not meant to be a definitive answer, and is based on dialect as opposed to proper English grammar--more of a commentary than an answer *per se*.

In colloquial American English, "completely Oxford" would be easily understood in the sense of "totally Oxford".  ("Totally" has been a popular term in colloquial American English.) Thus is works, but perhaps not in the context in which you intend to use it, where more words are necessary to convey the precise meaning.

- "Absolutely Oxford" is superior because of the alliterative quality

It has a better ring, but is not otherwise distinct structurally, so far as I know, in that completely and absolutely are both adverbs and synonyms.

Comment: If it's "easily understood", what the heck does it mean?

Comment: In this sense it means "I am 100% committed to Oxford as a choice."

Comment: Well, they're nice shoes, but I don't think many people wear them anymore.

Comment: That was my first thought! It reminded me of colloquial American English when I heard my student say "My first choice is completely Oxford". So that's what I was thinking of! 

I agree that it has a better ring, but I guess grammatically speaking both ABSOLUTELY and COMPLETELY work..? They are synonyms and boh adverbs after all. I wonder if this is just a matter of it sounding more natural or precise in terms of what the student wants to say.

Comment: @AnnaMinkova Yes, your idea toward the end of your comment is correct. That's basically what's happening. It sounds more idiomatic to native speakers b/c that is how we talk; and therefore that is what we hear all the time.

Answer (score 0):

(1)The clausal adverb "completely" must modify a verb, but (2)"My first choice is Oxford" has no verb to modify.

On (1), I rely on McCawley's classification of adverbs (see p. 197 and elsewhere in [The Syntactic Phenomena of English](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&q=completely#v=snippet&q=completely&f=false)).

On (2), although "is" bears a tense, which is a morphological characteristic of verbs, it is an auxiliary and behaves syntactically unlike true verbs.

Comment: This appears to be an excellent answer, but could be improved with a conclusion.

Comment: Which is why the original is confusing.  "Completely Oxford" is treating "Oxford" as an adjective, and hence "Oxford" is taken to be a descriptive term rather than a conventional noun.

Comment: @HotLicks, yes.  I intended "clausal adverb" to exclude the interpretation that "completely" is an adjective inside a NP or AdjP.